# How to avoid side effects while using Binding in JavaFX between model and view?

Tags: javafx, binding

Let me explain my problem with the following vehicle example:

I've got:

- IntegerProperty: **speed**
- BooleanProperty: **crash**
- JavaFX slider element: **speed_slider**. (where I can set a speed from 0-50.)
- JavaFX button element: **crash_button**.

I've successfully done:

Bound **speed** to the value of **speed_slider**.
That works. When I'm changing the value of the **speed_slider**, the **speed** changes.

But now I want to expand this. I tried the following:

Bound **crash** to the selectedValue of **crash_button**.
Bound **speed** to: if **crash** false, then value of **speed_slider**, else value 0.

Up here it works: Whenever **crash** is true, **speed** turns 0. If **crash** is false, it takes the value of **speed_slider**. And here is the problem:
I want  the **speed_slider** value is automatically changes to 0, when **speed** does change to 0 due to **crash**. When I try to bind the value of **speed_slider** to **speed** it does not work, it causes an endless loop and fails- how to solve that problem without using listeners?

Comment: Why do you need to do it without using listeners? (After all, how do you think bindings are implemented?)

Comment: I want to solve it without using listeners - but it does not seem to work.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do it without using listeners. You can't bind the value of the speed slider (because the user would not be able to change it), and you can't force it to be zero on the basis of another property without either binding it or using a listener. So you need a listener. I just don't understand why you want to avoid using listeners: that's exactly what they're for.

Comment: ok, I've already thought that, but wanted to know if there is any hint. thank you. I'm going to uselisteners for view-elements, so I can still manipulate them.

Comment: something wrong in the code you are not showing? Too lazy to really follow your text without seeing a SSCCE - might be that @James_D is right (he usually is :-) and it can't be done. Not quite convinced, though - it's all a matter of modeling ...

Comment: my question is not really about the code - that's why I've made an example to show the issue, while having troubles connecting view and model elements only with "Bindings". As I already recognized and @James_D already mentioned: Whenever I bind the value of the viewElement (slider) to another value, I can't manipulate the slider(value) afterwards - and that was my main problem and also question.

Comment: @DoeDoe Please explain why you need to do this "without using listeners". That's the part of your question that makes absolutely no sense at all.

Comment: I wanted to know, if there is any way to solve it without listeners. But it seems that there is no other way.

Comment: Why? You question basically reads "I know there is an API provided to solve exactly the problem I want to solve. How can I solve my problem with using the API that is provided for solving my problem?"

Comment: if you need bidi binding (aka: change from both ends) then use well  ... bidi-binding ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is simple, instead of unidirectional bindings, use bidirectional:

```
speed.bindBidirectional(speed_slider.valueProperty());
```

Then you can still do a unidirectional binding with the crash and others etc. All this does is make sure the slider is always in sync with the speed, no matter which of these change.